# Best mysql table design for every day adding new data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create database storing game data for about 1000 players, there is 16 stats for each user and each stat has level, experience, rank in game, rank on my website so each user has 16x4 records about stats. I want to track every day changes, thus store old data and every day add new. And there is problem, I am not really sure how to do that to keep my database fast. I thought about this solution but I am not sure if it is good (I am a bit new to mysql and haven't much experience with creating databases, hope this isn't one of the stupid questions)

I thought about creating one table for each player and every day add one row, however, I am afraid that 1000 tables is too much and will slow my database.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

your table [stats] could look like this

```
id | player_id | level | experience | game_rank | site_rank | stat_date
```

and you can create a scheduled task to move older data to a copy table [old_stats]
and keep say last 2 or 3 days data for each player

Comment: wont this lead to slow performance after some time when withdrawing old data? this way I'd have to add 1000 rows per day (for each player one)

Comment: if you are moving older data to old_stats table it will not cause slow performance at least when getting data from stats table, and you will be adding 1 row/each player every day, as 1 row will hold all stats data, no need to insert row for each type of stat.